# Curl and array values in curlopt_url does not work

Tags: php, arrays, curl

i have a very weird issue with curl and url defined inside an array.

I have an array of url and i want perform an http GET on those urls with curl

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($array_station) ; $i < $n ; $i++)
{
    $station= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_URL, $array_station[$i]);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $response = curl_exec($station);
    curl_close($station);
}
```

If i define my $array_station in the way below

```
$array_station=array("http://www.example.com","http://www.example2.com");
```

the code above with curl working flawlassy,but since my $array_station is build in the way below (i perform a scan of directory searchin a specific filename, then i clean the url), the curl does not work, no error showed and nothing happens..

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di);

$array_station=array();
$i=0;
foreach($it as $file) {
    if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) == "db_insert") {
        $string = str_replace('/web/htdocs/', 'http://', $file.PHP_EOL);
        $string2 = str_replace('/home','', $string);
        $array_station[$i]=$string2;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Doyou have some ideas? i'm giving up :-(

Comment: Please post the URL list that gets generated by your `foreach` loop.  Tip: do it from a directory with little in it!  Also, tell us specifically what curl returns when it "doesn't work."  I assume you know that you've spelled the array differently in the foreach loop code.

Comment: what is your loop actually generating? `var_dump($array_stazioni);` after the loop, what do you get?

Comment: @JeffLearman sorry buti can not post them since they are php urls that will generate an sql insert inside a db.Thery are simply url like this http://www.example.com/station/db_insert.php without space before and after

Comment: @hanshenrik i tried the var_dump you mentioned and it reports that all values are strings

Comment: can you also attach the `var_dump` result?

Comment: @ariefbayu
array(7) { [0]=> string(57) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/arsoli/db_insert.php" [1]=> string(59) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/cecchina/db_insert.php" [2]=> string(60) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/civitella/db_insert.php" [3]=> string(56) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/faete/db_insert.php" [4]=> string(56) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/nesce/db_insert.php" [5]=> string(64) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/roma_bravetta/db_insert.php" [6]=> string(59) "http://www.example.com/stazioni/roma_eur/db_insert.php" }

Comment: I saw one fatal variable error above: you initialized curl into `$stazione` yet process everything using `$station`...

Comment: @ariefbayu yes sorry it was a mistake reporting the code here in stackoverflow, i corrected the snippet above

Comment: In that case, I guess the issue is because of `str_replace()` is replacing non existence string into `http://`. If this also wrong, then I'm sorry, I don't know what else...

Comment: @ariefbayu could you please explain better?thanks!

Comment: your `var_dump`ed data contain only `example.com` where it should be in `http://example.com`

Comment: @ariefbayu yes i know it' due to stackoverflow that removes the http:// part, but in the array it's not missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile right now so i cannot test it, but why are you adding a new line (PHP_EOL) to the url? Try to remove the new line or `trim()` the url at the end.

Comment: @ariefbayu  i agree..by the way,i remved the PHP_EOL now but it still doesn't work

Comment: I also agree, but i couldnt find the add comment button on the app :p

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines of code below.

If there is a curl error it will report the error number.

If the request is made, it will show the HTTP request and response headers.  The request is in $info and response header is in $head

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($array_station) ; $i < $n ; $i++)
{
    $station= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_URL, $array_station[$i]);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($station, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $response = curl_exec($station);

    if (curl_errno($station)){
        $response .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($station);
    }
    else {
      $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($station, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
      $head = substr($response ,0,$skip);
      $response = substr($response ,$skip);
      $info = var_export(curl_getinfo($station),true);
    }
    echo $head;
    echo $info;



    curl_close($station);
}
```

Comment: I tried but no error is showd, $head and $info are empty, the code is executed apparently in a correct way, but without performin the curl call....stil i don't understand why.... :-(

Comment: What about $response?  If $head and $info are blank  there must be an curl error in $response..  I did not echo $response.  I suspect the URL does not conform.  echo the URL.  Maybe missing www.

Comment: Everything is empty, also response. The url inside the array are correct http www etc etc... it's a mistery..... :-/

Comment: Which array, $it or $array_station?  Or both?  Why $string, it is not being used.   PS you do not need $i, just use  $array_station[] = $string2;  And *mystery